# Devolver una categoria por cada seccion arreglos(dimensionales)

Tags: php, array, arraylist, lógica

Buen día coders,

Tengo el siguiente problema tengo este array

```
    $datos = '[{
        "ordenBoleta": "1",
        "idMateria": "MATEM\u00c1TICAS",
        "categoria": "FORMACI\u00d3N ACAD\u00c9MICA",
        "nombreMateria": "MATEM\u00c1TICAS",
        "1\u00b0 BIMESTRE": "10",
        "2\u00b0 BIMESTRE": "7",
        "3\u00b0 BIMESTRE": "5"
    }, {
        "ordenBoleta": "1",
        "idMateria": "LG ESPA\u00d1OL",
        "categoria": "FORMACI\u00d3N ACAD\u00c9MICA",
        "nombreMateria": "ESPA\u00d1OL",
        "1\u00b0 BIMESTRE": "10",
        "2\u00b0 BIMESTRE": "10",
        "3\u00b0 BIMESTRE": "8"
   }, {
        "ordenBoleta": "2",
       "idMateria": "EDUFISICA",
       "categoria": "DESARROLLO PERSONAL Y SOCIAL",
       "nombreMateria": "EDUCACI\u00d3N FISICA",
       "1\u00b0 BIMESTRE": "10",
       "2\u00b0 BIMESTRE": "9",
       "3\u00b0 BIMESTRE": "5"
   }, {
       "ordenBoleta": "2",
       "idMateria": "ARTES",
       "categoria": "DESARROLLO PERSONAL Y SOCIAL",
       "nombreMateria": "ARTES",
       "1\u00b0 BIMESTRE": "10",
       "2\u00b0 BIMESTRE": "8",
       "3\u00b0 BIMESTRE": "6"
    }]';
```

---

Este es el código php

```
 $datos2 = json_decode($datos,true);
 //primero obtenemos las categorias y las guaardamos
 $categorias = array();
 foreach($datos2 as $key => $campos){
   $categorias[] = $campos['categoria'];    
 }
 //arreglo temporal
 $unicos = array_unique($categorias);
 var_dump($categorias); 
 $c = 0;
 $t= 0; 
 foreach($datos2 as $key => $campos){   

    if($categorias[$c] == !empty($categorias[$c+1])){
        echo $categorias[$c]."<br>";

    }

    echo $campos['nombreMateria']."<br>";
    echo "1° BIMESTRE: ".$campos['1° BIMESTRE']."<br>";
    echo "2° BIMESTRE: ".$campos['2° BIMESTRE']."<br>";
    echo "3° BIMESTRE: ".$campos['3° BIMESTRE']."<br>"; 
    $c++;       
 }
```

Quisiera juntar las asignaturas si pertenecen a la misma categoría, porque está impriiendo el campo "categoria", varias veces, dejo una imagen para que tenga más sentido, ya llevo un rato tratano y nada.

Saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo el problema, quieres juntar las asignaturas si comparten categoría?

Comment: Sí, exacto. eso mismo

Comment: Pues tendrás que tratar la información, ahora te limitas a recorrer e imprimir.

Comment: @AsieR_2 ¿Te refieres a traer la información ya filtrada desde la BD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con el array como lo tienes, puedes poner un condicional dentro del bucle comparando la categoría actual con la siguiente, imprimiendo solamente cuando sean diferentes.

```
$json = json_decode($datos,true);
$previous="";
foreach ($json as $campos){
    $current=$campos["categoria"];
    if ($current !== $previous) {
        echo "<br />Categoría: $current<br /><hr />";
    }
    $previous = $current;
    echo "<br />".$campos['nombreMateria'].":<br /><br />";
    echo "1° BIMESTRE: ".$campos['1° BIMESTRE']."<br />";
    echo "2° BIMESTRE: ".$campos['2° BIMESTRE']."<br />";
    echo "3° BIMESTRE: ".$campos['3° BIMESTRE']."<br />";      
}
```

Tendrías esta salida.

Te la dejo en snippet para que puedas verla.

Espero te sirva.

```html
    <br>
    Categoría: FORMACIÓN ACADÉMICA<br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    MATEMÁTICAS:<br>
    <br>
    1° BIMESTRE: 10<br>
    2° BIMESTRE: 7<br>
    3° BIMESTRE: 5<br>
    <br>
    ESPAÑOL:<br>
    <br>
    1° BIMESTRE: 10<br>
    2° BIMESTRE: 10<br>
    3° BIMESTRE: 8<br>
    <br>
    Categoría: DESARROLLO PERSONAL Y SOCIAL<br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    EDUCACIÓN FISICA:<br>
    <br>
    1° BIMESTRE: 10<br>
    2° BIMESTRE: 9<br>
    3° BIMESTRE: 5<br>
    <br>
    ARTES:<br>
    <br>
    1° BIMESTRE: 10<br>
    2° BIMESTRE: 8<br>
    3° BIMESTRE: 6<br>
```

Comment: Excelente, justo lo que necesitaba, gracias!